# Android forgetting default launcher every few minutes

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, launcher, default-applications, htc-one

Starting last week, my HTC One running ARHD 31.5 keeps forgetting the default launcher. Every few minutes, it will forget the setting and ask me for a launcher when I hit the home button.

So far, I haven't found a pattern yet. Here's what I've tried so far:

- restarting the phone
- removing the default setting via `Settings > Apps` and setting it fresh
- tried different launchers to rule out the launcher deleting the settings
- updating the ROM (seriously)

It happens both when the phone is locked, or when I keep it unlocked and basically not doing anything but keeping the screen alive. After a few minutes, the default will be gone.

Any ideas how to debug this are welcome.

Comment: when you say it forgets the default launcher, what other launcher are you using?

Comment: It's forgetting Aviate. But I have also tried setting Nova Launcher or the default HTC Sense launcher as the default and it forgets them as well.

Comment: I just got the tip to try looking at "adb logcat" to see if something comes up and I get this log message: 

`Result set changed, dropping preferred activity for Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] } type null`

I'm just trying to get the context of that to see if this helps find out what is happening.

Comment: When it asks you to select a default launcher, do you select `Always`, instead of `Just once`?

Comment: Yes, I select "Always".

Comment: As far as I understand the message, the list of applications providing the home button intent is changing (or the system thinks that it is changing).

To narrow it down I have just removed Aviate and switch to Nova Launcher. The problem still exists, so I'll now try removing Nova and reinstalling Aviate.
Removing both probably won't help because then there will only be one launcher available and nothing to choose from.

Comment: Last update: Disabling/removing either Aviate or Nova Launcher does not help, the setting will still get lost.

Comment: If there is no more Aviate or Nova, what do you mean by setting will still get lost? I would assume there will only be 1 launcher left.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear: I only removed one of them at a time so I always had HTC Sense plus one custom launcher to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

It's still unclear what is causing this to happen and I have found only one other mention of the problem so far. In the end I simply disabled the stock launcher by freezing it using Titanium Backup and also disabled all other custom launchers. Soon as only one launcher is available, the dialog goes away. More of a workaround then a solution, so if anyone has an idea how to continue debugging, then I'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue likewise on Nexus 4 and on Nexus 7 (2012), with Android 4.3 and persistent after updating to Android 4.4.
As I don't have rooted devices, the only 'solution' I've seen was deinstalling the nova launcher. Nova launcher was the only alternative launcher I've had installed and with only the default launcher left, the dialog is gone.
A pity, though, as Nova enhances the user experience considerably.

Comment: There was one similar report here [link](http://www.techhelpfox.com/3984345/Wierd-Problem-Home-Button-Reset-Itself-And-Loses-Default-Launcher-Setting). One commenter tracked his issue down to the app MoboPlayer, but this didn't seem to apply to the thread starter and the other respondents. Also I don't have that app installed. So the issue is possibly related to an unknown setting which can be influenced by apps.

Comment: Yes, I read that thread as well. Unfortunately I also didn't have that app. Good to hear that the problem showed up with the 4.4 update for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is strange, I also go the same problem. But then, I used titanium backup to move the default launcher from a system app to user app. Only after that, I am able to set other launcher as default.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Fix Permissions" option in the custom recovery. Also try wiping caches and Dalvik Cache. If they didn't work try disabling any cleaners, taskers, etc. Also check "Accessibility" in settings to see if there are any services that could potentially be causing the problem.   I would recommend doing these sequentially (but not necessarily in any particular order), so  you can isolate what was causing the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Scan all the applications installed to see if there are any `android:proprity="-1"` in `intent-filter`s. (I know `com.taobao.taobao` breaks)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings -> Home. If there is any non launcher app (E.g. Times Job), then remove it and select the launcher you want as default. That might solve the problem.

Comment: Is "Settings -> Home" available in 4.3 JB? I'm aware of Kitkat having it, and JB 4.2.1 doesn't have such entry.